# PicklingError in pyspark (PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Person'>: attribute lookup Person on __main__ failed)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-ml, pickle

I am unable to pickle the below class. I am using data bricks 6.5 ML (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11)

````
import pickle
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
p1 = Person("John", 36)
pickle.dump(p1,open('d.pkl','wb'))```

PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Person'>: attribute lookup Person on __main__ failed
````

Answer (score 3):

Possible answer from [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/27818/)

> The problem is that you're trying to pickle an object from the module where it's defined. If you move the class into a separate file and import it into your script, then it should work.

That solution isn't viable for me in an iPython notebook though. So here I some additional information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48623956/4367134)

> Python's pickle actually does not serializes classes: it does
> serialize instances, and put in the serialization a reference to each
> instance's class - and that reference is based on the class being
> bound to a name in a well defined module. So, instances of classes
> that don't have a module name, but rather live as attribute in other
> classes, or data inside lists and dictionaries, typically will not
> work.
>
> One straight forward thing one can try to do is try to use dill
> instead of pickle. It is a third party package that works like
> "pickle" but has extensions to actually serialize arbitrary dynamic
> classes.
>
> While using dill may help other people reaching here, it is not your
> case, because in order to use dill, you'd have to monkey patch the
> underlying RPC mechanism PySpark is using to make use of dill instead
> of pickle, and that might not be trivial nor consistent enough for
> production use.
>
> If the problem is really about dynamically created classes being
> unpickable, what you can do is to create extra meta-classes, for the
> dynamic classes themselves, instead of using "type", and on these
> metaclasses, create proper **getstate** and **setstate** (or other
> helper methods as it is on pickle documentation) - that might enable
> these classes to be pickled by ordinary Pickle. That is, a separate
> metaclass with Pickler helper methods to be used instead of type(...,
> (object, ), ...) in your code.
>
> However, "unpickable object" is not the error you are getting - it is
> an attribute lookup error, which suggests the structure you are
> building is not good enough for Pickle to introspect into it and get
> all the members from one of your instances - it is not related (yet)
> to the unpickleability of the class object. Since your dynamic classes
> live as attributes on the class (which is not itself pickled) and not
> of the instance, it is very well possible that pickle does not care
> about it. Check the docs on pickle above, and maybe all you need there
> is proper helper-method to pickle on you class, nothing different on
> the the metaclass for all that you have there to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining a Class, try defining a NamedTuple instead.

```
import pickle
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple("Person", "name age")

p1 = Person("John", 36)
pickle.dump(p1,open('d.pkl','wb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Put class Person into a separate e.g. "utility.py"

```
import utility
import pickle
 
new_person = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(utility.Person()))
```

It solved my ipykernel issue!